# Right-To-Left appearance of SWT Text fields

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, right-to-left, bidi

I am expecting a weird problem with **some** of the Text fields in my Eclipse-RCP application: when I start typing text in these fields it appears in the reverse order (right-to-left). For instance: typing "hello", appears as "olleh". Even if I put caret to the end of the text it will jump to the beginning, when typing next letter.

All fields are created in the same way, but not all of them have such strange behavior. If I right-click on the field and select "Show Unicode control characters" it does not show that there is a right-to-left bidi character.

Has anyone expected something similar or have any clues of what is wrong with my application?

Comment: What does `getOrientation()` on the `Text` field return?

Comment: Orientation is LEFT_TO_RIGHT :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved, so, I am gonna post an answer, in case someone comes across the same problem.

Apparently, orientation was not changed to right_to_left. Initial problem was, that during typing caret was jumping to the beginning of the text field (after each symbol). And the reason for such behavior was, that there were multiple `Bindings` created for one `TextField` (sub and parent classes were creating these bindings).

Comment: How did you find about it? Would you like to share the source? You cannot have a midnight revelation do you?

Comment: Well, there is no source: debugging and thinking has helped:)

Comment: Thank you. I had the exact same problem and you've saved me a heap of time

Answer (score 1):

Try `text.setOrientation(SWT.LEFT_TO_RIGHT)`

[Here is the Eclipse Documentation of `Text`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FText.html). If this doesn't help, you might try reworking whatever layout you're using; I can't be more specific without an example.

Comment: `setOrientation(int)` is a hint and does not work on all platforms - Mac OS X Cocoa for one. The orientation needs to be set in the initial constructor style.

Comment: How could the orientation be right-to-left by default, if it is not set explicitly anywhere? More over only on some fields. In which way layouts affect text fields orientation?

Comment: I don't know how giving the link for documentation help. Pointing to specific page would be ideal. If you want to ask him to visit documentation. Kindly write so.